# How to get delivery report from SMSC using Jamaa-Smpp and C#?

Tags: sms-gateway, smpp

How to get delivery report from SMSC using Jamaa-Smpp and C#?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get delivery report in Jamaa-Smpp by using client_MessageDelivered event

First ,we need to use this code:

```
SmppClient(); client = new SmppClient();
client.MessageDelivered += new EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>(client_MessageDelivered);
```

Second , we need to use this code:

```
 void client_MessageDelivered(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        TextMessage msg = e.ShortMessage as TextMessage;
        string msgtext=msg.text;
    }
```

and do not forget to set value to SubmitSm.RegisteredDelivery as your work requirements:

```
//SMSC delivery receipt requested where final delivery outcome is deliver success or failure

SubmitSm.RegisteredDelivery = RegisteredDelivery.DeliveryReceipt;
```

or

```
//SMSC delivery receipt requested where the final delivery outcome is delivery failure

SubmitSm.RegisteredDelivery = RegisteredDelivery.DeliveryReceiptFailure;
```